# Chromium Web Apps will not install after I am prompted. Unity extension is installed

Tags: unity, 13.04, chromium, webapps

Chromium Web Apps will not install even after I am prompted. The unity extension is installed. This is a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit install and the system was updated directly after the installation.

Is anyone else having this problem with Chromium? How can I fix this?